# Is there a version of the simple slider for Polymer 1.0

Tags: slider, polymer, polymer-1.0

Trying to use an image slider in a website we are building with Polymer 1.0. Couldn't find any readily usable ones. The one we found is for the older version.

https://github.com/ruyadorno/polymer-simple-slider

Is there an easy way to port this to the newer version of Polymer? Or is there another image slider we can use?

Comment: Generally, this is not the right place for this sort of question, the google plus community is good and there is http://customelements.io which is a good catalogue. That being said he's something I've been working on recently https://github.com/Link2Twenty/l2t-paper-slider

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the pointer Andrew.